# How to add product data to the search field in angular

Tags: angular

I have a two-component navbar and product, and in the navbar component, I have a search box, and I want to search the product data from the product component, and I don't know how to do this, so please anyone help me with this.

Comment: you can check official angular document to know how to do [Component interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#component-interaction)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with BehaviorSubject and making one common service between these both comoponents.

Create new service and make BehaviorSubject in it.

```
search_value = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
```

In navbar import that service and on change of search value set value in search_value like this :

```
search_value.next(search_box_value);
```

In product page import service and subscribe search_value like this :

```
search_value.subscribe((data)=>{
  // you will get search box value in data
},(error)=>{
  // you can handle error if any
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the API with serach text as id and get the search list and store the list in service and display the list in html using *ngfor.Refer the below code:

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="searchText" placeholder="Search" >
       <button type="submit" (click)="searchdetails()"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
    
Ts:
    searchText: any;
     public searchdetails(){
    this.search=this.searchText;
    this.productservice.searchdetails(this.search);
   

  }
 Service:
  //Get the Detail from API 
  public searchdetails(searchText: string) {

    this.http.get(this.rootUrl + '/SearchProduct/' + searchText).toPromise().then(res => this.list = res as products[])
  }
```